# How to generate a Changelog file using git post-receive hook?

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like that every time that some push or merge happen in the Master branch, I would like to run a script python to update the Changelog.md file on the gitlab repository.

It that possible ? I couldn't find any solution for that.

I would like to generate the changelog on the server-side and not on the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

If you regularly tag your work I would suggest this additional CI step as an inspiration. All your commit messages along with their associated hash will appear in a bullet point list as the change log or rather the release notes:

```
release:
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli:latest
  stage: release
  script:
   - export DATE=$(date +"%Y.%m.%d")
   - git tag -l | grep $DATE
   - git log --oneline $(git describe --tags --abbrev=0 @^)..@ > desc.md
   - sed -i 's/^/- /' desc.md
   - cat desc.md
  release:
    tag_name: '$(date +"%Y.%m.%d")'
    description: desc.md
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
```